# gsoap error: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]

Tags: gsoap

I downloaded gsoap 2.8 and went into the samples folder and ran a make.  Everything seems to have built fine.  I then navigated into the "ssl" folder and ran the sllserver in one xterm and ran sslclient in a second xterm window.  (I am running RHEL 6)  The server seems to run fine, it says "Bind successful: socket = 4".  But when I run the client I receive the following message:

> Error -1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
>   "End of file or no input: Operation interrupted or timed out (30 s receive delay) (30 s send delay)"
>   Detail: [no detail]

I have not modified any of the sample code, so it seems like it should just work.  Can anyone please give me some advice as to what I should look at?  I am trying to learn how to set up a soap server that uses ssl. (I have a gsoap server running already)  I searched all day for an example on the web and as usual, there is not one.

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could rebuild this example with compiler switch `-DDEBUG` to enable message logging (`make 'sslclient_CFLAGS = -DWITH_OPENSSL -DWITH_GZIP -DDEBUG'`). The `TEST.log` will tell what went wrong. I suspect it is a network issue with the server address/port that is set by default to `"https://localhost:18081"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the timeout parameter: `soap.recv_timeout = 60` (for 60 seconds)

Comment: I somehow don't think this will help, 30s on localhost should be more than enough.